# Moving a value from 1 table to another

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-office, office-2007

What's the best way to do the following using access 2007?

I want to move a value from 1 table to another.  If `table1` has the value `1000`, I would like to move some of that value to `table2`.  Lets say I want to move `50` to `table2` from `table1`.  The end result should be that `table1` is left with `950`, and `table2` is left with `50` if it started with `0`, i.e. `50` has been moved from `table1` to `table2`.

I can't seem to do this with access 2007 sql.

I have the following so far which will be based on a form later, but for now I have hard coded the `50` value, but it gives me a syntax error:

```
insert into table2
(value)
select 50
from table1 where id = 1;
update table1
set value = (value - 50)
where id = 1;
```

The insert, select and update work fine when separated, but when combined linke this, they don't work.

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: i do not think this is valid syntax in any sql syntax. what's the problem with executing two separate sql statements?

Comment: @parakmiakos How do I do that with a single button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA you can do the following (on a button click for example):

```
Private Sub Button1_OnClick()
    Dim s as String

    s = " insert into table2 (value) select 50 from table1 where id = 1; "
    CurrentDb.Execute s
    s = " update table1 set value = (value - 50) where id = 1;  "
    CurrentDb.Execute s
End Sub
```